# QT console application with Crypto++ library

Tags: c++, macos, qt, x86-64, crypto++

This is driving me nuts. Using crypto++ ver 5.6.2. Qt 5.2.1 on Mac OSX.
All the projects are built inside QT Creator.  Im not using make from the command line

I build crypto++ by unpacking and building as follow:

1. qmake -project
2. Deleted the GNUmakefile
3. Open in QT and modified the .pro file by adding

   ```
   macx {
       DEFINES += CRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM
   }
   ```

The target is cryptopp:

```
TARGET = cryptopp
```

Set to release, ran qmake and did a rebuild all.  The dylibs get generated:

- libcryptopp.1.0.0.dylib
- libcryptopp.1.0.dylib (Alias)
- libcryptopp.1.dylib (Alias)
- libcryptopp.dylib (Alias)

Created a bare console application and included my crypto class.
Modified the .pro file as follow:

```
macx {

    # CONFIG += release cryptopp
    LIBS += /Users/adviner/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/clang_64/lib/libcryptopp.1.0.0.dylib

    QMAKE_POST_LINK += install_name_tool -change libcryptopp.1.0.0.dylib $$[QT_INSTALL_LIBS]/libcryptopp.1.0.0.dylib $(TARGET)
}
```

In the console test app in debug mode.  Ran qmake and then rebuild all.  I keep getting the following error:

```
:-1: error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
:-1: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've checked both the projects and they both include x86_64) in the qmake build steps:

```
cryptopp lib:
qmake /Users/myname/Projects/QTLibs/Source/crypto/cryptopp562/cryptopp562.pro -r -spec macx-clang CONFIG+=x86_64
```

Test console app:

```
qmake /Users/myname/Projects/Test/CryptoTest/CryptoTest.pro -r -spec macx-clang CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=x86_64 CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug
```

Ive done some google search but nothing seems to answer my problem.  Any ideas?  I have built the same crypto++ lib on windows using Qt 5.2.1 and used in my app with no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK i finally figured it out.  When I built the crypto++ lib on the Mac I added as described above:

```
macx {
    DEFINES += CRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM
}
```

Well on the console application I had to also add this in the .pro file and it works now

I found the following tip also to modify

/Users/adviner/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang/qmake.conf

From
    QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.6

To
    QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.9

But it didnt do anything for me.

Only solution was to put on both lib and test the CRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM

Comment: You should no longer need `-DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM` for Clang. I think we have worked out all the LLVM and Apple Clang issues. Its currently available in Master, and will be available in 5.6.4 and above. It should not longer be needed in 5.6.3 ZIP file, but I can't say for certain. I think we only got part of the fixes cut-in.